# Por que a NavBar persiste mesmo após a mudança de página?

Tags: flutter, nav-bar, cross-platform

Eu fiz uma tela em Flutter usando o Cupertino, que ao clicar no campo "unidade", abriria uma tela "Unidade" para escolher a unidade, porém a NavigationBar que era usada em uma tela, está sendo passada para outra sem ao menos eu passa-la para a outra página, e eu não estou sabendo como resolver o problema;

Imagem Tela:

[image]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PlatformTabScaffold(
  tabController: tabController,
  appBarBuilder: (_, index) => PlatformAppBar(
    android: (_) => MaterialAppBarData(
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    ios: (_) => CupertinoNavigationBarData(
        backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
        title: Text(
          titulo,
          style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black),
        )),
    title: (Text(titulo)),
  ),
  bodyBuilder: (context, index) => textPage(tabController.index(context)),
  itemChanged: (int a) {
    setState(() {
      titulo = pageName(a);
    });
  },
  iosTabs: (_) => CupertinoTabBarData(
    // Aba de Navegação do IOS
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), title: Text('Iniciar Dia')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.local_shipping), title: Text('Abastecer')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.stop), title: Text('Finalizar Dia')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.local_gas_station), title: Text('Tanque')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.equalizer), title: Text('Mais opções')),
    ],
    backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.lightBackgroundGray,
    activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
    inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.inactiveGray,
  ),
  androidTabs: (_) => MaterialNavBarData(
    //Aba de  Navegação do Android
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange[700],
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.white70,
    showSelectedLabels: true,
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow), title: Text('Iniciar Dia')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.local_shipping), title: Text('Abastecer')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close), title: Text('Finalizar Dia')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.local_gas_station), title: Text('Tanque')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          icon: Icon(Icons.equalizer),
          title: Text('Mais opções')),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Ao Clicar em "Unidade"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';

class UnidadeOpcoes extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_UnidadeOpcoesState createState() => _UnidadeOpcoesState();
}

class _UnidadeOpcoesState extends State<UnidadeOpcoes> {
  var _currencies1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
  bool check = false;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PlatformScaffold(
  appBar: PlatformAppBar(
    title: Text("Unidade"),
    android: (_)   => MaterialAppBarData(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: true,

    ),
    ios: (_) => CupertinoNavigationBarData(
      trailing: CupertinoButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
        child: Text("Salvar"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      automaticallyImplyMiddle: true,
      leading: CupertinoButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
        child: Text("Cancelar"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: Text("Teste"),
  ios: (_) => CupertinoPageScaffoldData(),
  android: (_) => MaterialScaffoldData(
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _currencies1.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              _currencies1[index],
            ),
            leading: check == false
                ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
                : Icon(Icons.check_box, color: Colors.blueAccent),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                check = !check;
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente isso ocorre devido ao fato da `CupertinoTabScaffold` controlar as rotas chamadas a partir dela.

> To push a route above all tabs instead of inside the currently
>   selected one (such as when showing a dialog on top of this scaffold),
>   use Navigator.of(rootNavigator: true) from inside the BuildContext of
>   a CupertinoTabView.
>
> Fonte:
>   [CupertinoTabcaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabScaffold-class.html)

Então para que a sua tela unidade seja chamada acima do *Scaffold* você precisa fazer dessa forma:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(...)
```

Comment: Se resolveu seu problema, favor marcar como aceita.